# Upload images with preview

Tags: jquery, html, image, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a panel for image uploading. I can upload and multiple of images. When I choose an image it displays in other panel (image preview). But my problem is that work for one image not for more than one. Here is my code.
That is the form for uploading.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "ImageAdvertisement", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();

    <h4><label><b><i>@GoOnWork.Resource.ChooseImage</i></b></label></h4>
    <input type="file" multiple="multiple" class="jfilestyle" name="file" id="file" style="width: 100%;margin: 0 auto;" data-buttontext="><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open'></span> Choose File"; />
    <input type="hidden" value="@Model" name="advertisementId" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="width:250px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> @GoOnWork.Resource.Upload</button>
}
```

And that is the panel where I display image before I upload it.

```
<div class="col-md-7 hidden" id="showImg">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading text-center"><b><i>@GoOnWork.Resource.ImagePreview</i></b></div>
        <div class="panel-body text-center">
            <img id="myImg" src="#" alt="your image" class="img-rounded" width="400" height="360" border="0" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my JQuery part of code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(":file").change(function () {
            if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
                reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
            }
        });
    });

    function imageIsLoaded(e) {
        $('#myImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
        $('#showImg').removeClass("hidden");
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can preview multiple images like following. Iterate through each image of the file upload, create an `<img>` with it and then append in to DOM.

```js
$('input[type="file"]').change(function() {
  $('.preview').html('');
  $.each(this.files, function() {
    readURL(this);
  })
});

function readURL(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    $('.preview').append('<img src=' + e.target.result + ' style="width: 100px; height: 120px;"/>');
  }

  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" multiple/>
<div class="preview"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! But if I can ask you, how can I make them in slider with next and previous button?

Comment: This a completely different issue. Ask new question for this. @DimitarGanichev

Answer (score 1):

In your javascript, you always reference the same img tag with the ID "myImg". Besides the fact that ids should be unique, this means that you always select the same element (even if there are several elements with the same id) and change its source attribute.

Rewrite your HTML and JS so that each added image has its own id on the image. Or you could go and rewrite your `imageIsLoaded` function so that it generates a new HTML block for each image